# While running npm run build for nextjs app in EC2 instance it is getting killed automatically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, amazon-web-services, next.js

I am trying to deploy my nextjs app on EC2 but when I was running npm run build it was getting killed automatically, so I thought it might be because of the ram so I changed my instance type to t3.medium which has 4GB ram but I am still having the same problem.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The optimization takes place because the ec2 instance **does not have enough memory** for **building** available for your Next app to run.

Again, the problem will arise only when running the command

```
$ npm run build
error due to not having enough memory
```

and not when you start the next app or run the command

```
$ npm start
should work as too much memory is not needed.
```

You have already tried increasing the memory (I do not recommend that as you are changing your instance and paying more for a task that you will run only once and that too can be done on any other machine) by changing the instance type. You can try some other ways:

Option 1: You can try to **optimize** your Next.js app by **removing unnecessary dependencies** and **minimizing the size of your assets**.

Option 2: You can try **building the Next.js app on another machine** (does not have to be Linux) with more memory and then transfer the build to the EC2 instance using ssh or WinSCP.

Option 3: use a service like AWS Elastic Beanstalk - This service automatically handles provisioning, load balancing, and automatic scaling for your Next.js application.

Option 1 may not be practical so I **recommend trying option 2 or 3**.

Answer (score 0):

you need to kill all running processing for that port, the one your app is using

ex:

```
lsof -i :3000 
kill <PID>
```

if you are running more then one next js apps in droplet or system, for me stopping them all then building worked.